# How to start mongo db on windows

Tags: mongodb, database

I am new to `mongo`, and I am trying to install mongo on my windows system. I am following THIS tutorial, but when I do

```
 C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe
```

my `CMD` gives me this output

```
2015-04-20T18:53:27.433+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in ini
en: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2015-04-20T18:53:27.436+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: You have to create that folders on c:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MongoDB requires a data directory to store all data. MongoDB’s default data directory path is `\data\db`.

Create this folder

```
md \data\db
```

You can specify an alternate path for data files using the `--dbpath` option to mongod.exe, for example:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
```

If your path includes spaces, enclose the entire path in double quotes,

for example:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath "d:\test\mongo db data"
```

[Read more in detail](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

Comment: I am using version 3.6, could not find mongod.conf to put the configurations, so I have to type "monog --dbpath path" everytime, therefore created a batch file for same to get it quickly, could not find any help how to make configuration changes in mongo 3.6

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the same using :

Create a folder **data** in

D:\project-workspace\mongodb\data

Then Create another folder **db** inside **data** 
ie,

D:\project-workspace\mongodb\data\db

Then run the command

```
mongod --dbpath D:\project-workspace\mongodb\data\db
```

Make sure you have set environment variable for mongodb else browse

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin
```

and then execute this =>

```
mongod.exe --dbpath E:\workspace\mongodb\data
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the similar problem on windows, moreover, i dont have my environment variable set so i have to go to bin folder and run mongo. Below are the steps i followed
1) I created a folder on my desktop something like **"C:\Desktop\data\"**
2) In order to use mongo shell, you need to run mongo which is similar to a daemon on unix, so in windows, we can do it by opening a command prompt window and change directory to mongo\bin and run 
**mongod --dbpath C:\Desktop\data** and left it runnning
3) I opened second command prompt window, did a change directory to C:\mongo\bin
and executed **mongod**, that's it

Answer (score 2):

Because MongoDB does not know the directory DB.

**Fixed Work for me.**

Step 1: New Folder e.g. Run cmd

```
mkdir  E:\workspace\mongodb\data
```

Step 2: Move to Root MongoDB path e.g. (cd .../MongoDB/.../bin/)

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongod.exe --dbpath E:\workspace\mongodb\data
```

Ok.

Answer (score 1):

Also faced the same issue in windows. if --dbpath directory path does not contain spaces, do not include quotes. Removing quotes, when the path does not have space, resolved the issue.

Comment: add some samples