# MongoDB: Not working in windows

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB is not connecting to the data bases. I added the path. 
Whenever I run `mongo` it attempts to connect to `test` byt fails.

Error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Couldn't connect to the server 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Someone please help me!

Comment: did you run `mongod.exe` before that?

Comment: Yes. I had done mongod.exe

Comment: i mean, do you have an active terminal with `mongod.exe` running?

Comment: Well, it's not running. I see a dbexit message at the end.

Comment: well, the `mongod.exe` needs to be active. follow the steps from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749949/how-to-start-mongo-db-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure Following:

> **Step1**: Set path in Environment Variable.

```
\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin;
```

> **Step 2**: Create data directory

```
 md \data
 md \data\d
```

> **Step 3**: Start mongo Shell

```
mongod
```

> **Step 4**: Start Mongo

```
mongo
```

This [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBdaRlgb4N8&index=9&list=PL6FHMytFXW44xQPgcWiKgR24GYZKLqhdn) from mongo university will help understand more easily.