# can't connect to MongoDb using mongoose. MongoDB installed in my local system

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I cant connect to MongoDb using mongoose. I have installed MongoDB in my local system

```
//Import the mongoose module
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    //Set up default mongoose connection`enter code here`
    var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/my_database';
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
      useMongoClient: true
    });

    //Get the default connection
    var db = mongoose.connection;

    //Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

    module.exports = mongoose.connection;
```

getting the error:

```
// MongoDB connection error: { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

Comment: try using  `mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/my_database`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Seemingly using `localhost` in your connection string is the issue. Best just use `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`. In linux both work well but windows the `localhost` has issues

Example:

```
const DB_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1/<db_name>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you start mongoDb with the command `mongod`
Maybe run it on a differnt port with `mongod --port 12345`

Comment: Well here is your issue "STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found."

Comment: I run mongod.exe. Following is the error..   MongoDB starting : pid=6652 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-2T8MJHS
 targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
l
[initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
[initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
[initandlisten] options: {}
[initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
[initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
[initandlisten] now exiting
[initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: Can you follow the instructions from this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749949/how-to-start-mongo-db-on-windows

Comment: thats a perfect fix. I have an another error while posting data.    (node:10100) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: You can ignore that error, with a callback it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hareesh, you need to test your code, more specifically, your connection between Mongoose and Mongo. Mongoose is just a library, it does not automatically connect to Mongo which is why you have the code above to tell it to do so, but you need to test that.

Create a test directory at the root of whatever it is you called this project. Inside of the test folder, create a test_helper.js file. Inside of it, you are going to write the code above, but refactor it into the ES6 model in this manner.

```
//Import the mongoose module
const mongoose = require(‘mongoose’);

//Set up default mongoose connection`enter code here
mongoose.connect(‘mongodb://localhost/project_test’);
mongoose.connection
     .once(‘open’, () => console.log(‘Good to go!’))
     .on(‘error’, (error) => {
        console.warn(‘Warning’, error);
});
```

Hope this helps.