# mongodb installation error connection failed on windows

Tags: mongodb

I have tried all solutions mentioned in below 2 links
[Mongodb: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585433/mongodb-failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-127017-reason-errno10061/31132332)
[How to start mongo db on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749949/how-to-start-mongo-db-on-windows)

But still getting below error

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongo MongoDB shell
>   version: 3.2.18-15-g678cb63 connecting to: test
>   2018-01-26T16:39:23.926+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
>   127.0.0.1 :27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up. 2018-01-26T16:39:23.927+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't
>   connect to ser ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14 @(connect):1:6
>
> exception: connect failed`

Comment: The question should have enough details in the question itself. Please add the config you are using and both commands you are executing to start mongod and to run mongo.

Comment: Hi Alex for mongod i an getting below log                                 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod                
         2018-01-26T16:39:14.713+0530 I CONTROL  [main]
2018-01-26T16:39:14.714+0530 W CONTROL  [main] 32-bit servers don't have journal
ing enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
  2018-01-26T16:39:14.727+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 678cb635ccb
nvironment:e exp
licitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
2018-01-26T16:39:14.733+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Comment: doesn't it answer the question? you can't connect because the server didn't start. As a side note, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to increase your chances to get an answer.

Comment: Hi Alex,what should i do to solve this issue?

Comment: You can start with updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Open onemore terminal  **as admin** and run `mongod`. After this you can start your app in main terminal.

Comment: Not close or stop second terminal where you open mongod. When you run mongod you starting mongo server. After this you can start your app in first terminal and it can connect to mongodb server, that you runed by mongod command in second terminal

Comment: I have mongodb installed in below path                                                           
C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

Created empty folder here 
C:\data\db


In Admin command promt i am using below command
C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod


Then in other command promt window i am giving below command
C:\Program Files (x86)\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongo


But still getting connection faliure error

Comment: I this this is issue 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not av
ailable with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine exp
licitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
2018-01-26T22:13:42.479+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Can someone please suggest what needs to do to solve this issue ?

Comment: i used mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1 and it worked,thanks Alex and Mikita

Comment: wow i didnt know that changing storage strategy can help. nice job! looks like that was cuz of low RAM.